# Unable get the proper altitude from gps satellite in android Device

Tags: android, gps, altitude

i am using `android` in my small spy `android helicopter`  i am getting proper `latitude` and `longitude` when it is above 500ft from the ground ,i am doing landing of my helicopter based on the height calculated from the `altitude` .but what i am getting as altitude most of the times  is wrong due to that my helicopter is crashing in the ground  do you have any idea how to get the proper altitude from `gps` satellite.and i am using `getAltitude()` method from getting `altitude`
and using in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your altitude is always wrong by a given, fixed offset?

Comment: No most of the time i am getting wrong altitude like i have recorded the same altitude when it was above 300ft from ground and also giving same altitude in ground level.that why my helicopter is crashing.

Comment: GPS has a margin of error. The location manager reports the estimated error. Also if your device has a pressure sensor you can use that to augment your calculation for altitude.

Answer (score 0):

Using GPS satellites for landing is very bad idea. Android is using ellipsoid earth approximation. In my location its give me 40 meters extra in data I'm receiving from GetAltidude(). Don't forget about inaccuracy of GPS signal which can add next more than 10 meters.